# (Python) locate certain field of image from image

Tags: python, ocr

**I want to extract certain part from the image**
*I am running Python 3.9.12 with CV2 4.6.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS*

(From) The original pic:
https://ibb.co/RcZ7ntL

(then) The pic want to locate(I want to extract the red part only):
https://ibb.co/dGBfqXx

**(the desire pic/output)** : https://ibb.co/j5h501f

I've tried searching for a solution on StackOverflow, but I didn't find anything remotely similar. And I search that most of the tutorial is teaching finding the same image in image.

In case someone doesn't want to load too many pics, I put them as link instead.

**so my main issue is that not sure how to cut them into the picture I want**

---

this is after I manual cut to the part I want, then I can do OCR recognize image to text

**the desire pic/output** : https://ibb.co/j5h501f

the pic I success detect the image to text:  https://ibb.co/mv9WTpW

---

I come up a idea [solution A]

1. that using openCV bounding box cut every sticker separated https://ibb.co/1Q9DnLJ
2. cause every line is fixed distance (ex: CA74C8), then give cv the correct scale to cut

**how to make [solution A] step 1 work? I have tried for half of a day but still stock on this, I need a hand thanks**

Answer (score 1):

You can do the reverse task:

run your OCR first, since it will find all texts in the image for you.

If you you [tesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/), it will send you all the text AND the locations/boxes where the text is found.

like [here](https://nanonets.com/blog/ocr-with-tesseract/):
[image]

Comment: thanks @Hu gePanic, that may a good direction, mine looks like this https://ibb.co/vVPsjdD, if can product like https://ibb.co/j5h501f, then is grateful for me

Comment: I cannot give you any good recommencdations on how to use it in detail. Just: the google-group for tesseract is pretty helpfull  https://groups.google.com/g/tesseract-ocr